# Distinguish between Integer and Double in V8

Tags: c++, c++11, v8

In my implementation I provide a function to JavaScript that accepts a parameter.

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> TableGetValueIdForValue(const v8::Arguments& args) {
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

  auto val = args[1];

  if (val->IsNumber()) {

    auto num = val->ToNumber();
    // How to check if Int or Double    

  } else { 
     // val == string 
  }
}
```

Now this parameter can have basically any type. As I support Int, Float and String I want to efficiently check for these types. Using `IsNumber()` and `IsStringObject()` I can make sure that the objects are numberish or a string.

But now I need to differentiate between an integer value and a float. What is the best way to perform this test? Is there a way to call / use the `typeof` function exposed to JS?

Comment: search for "class Value" in http://izs.me/v8-docs/v8_8h_source.html.  There are functions `bool Value::IsInt32` and `double Value::NumberValue` which could be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

### Quick Answer

**v8::Value::NumberValue()** will will return the value of the javascript *Number* without loss of precision.

### Explanation

It is true that the set of numbers representable by ***int64_t*** and ***double*** is different.  And so is natural to be concerned about what happens if the value is actually ***int64_t*** because v8::Value defines both

```
V8EXPORT int64_t v8::Value::IntegerValue() const;
V8EXPORT double v8::Value::NumberValue() const;
```

#### What is a v8::Number?

Consider v8::Number doc

> > #### Detailed Description
> >
> > A JavaScript number value ([ECMA-262, 4.3.20](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19))

**IntegerValue** does return an ***int64_t***, but there will be [no more precision available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t), because the value is stored internally as a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value.

#### Testing in a browser

Checking if javascript can represent a value that a ***double*** can't but an ***int64_t*** can.

> 2^63 - 1  is equal to 9223372036854775807

Try typing the following in a javascript console; this value is parsed but the extra precision is thrown away because double can't represent it.

```
>9223372036854775807
```

the result

```
9223372036854776000
```

Comment: `v8::Value::NumberValue() will will return the value of the javascript Number without loss of precision.`

This helped me add to a double I had already defined, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try `IsInt32` or `IsUint32()` to check the number is integer or not.

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L1313

Comment: Thanks, this is true, however there is a light problem here: If you look at the implementation of the method in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/api.cc#L2641 you will see that it first checks for `IsSmi()` (small integer) and than further checks if the double representation can be converted forth and back to/from an integer to see if the value is stable. Thus a value like `3.0` would be treated as an integer, even though it's a `Number`. Any comments on that?

Comment: As far as JavaScript semantics is concerned, 3.0 *is* an integer. Whether V8 internally represents it as a float or not is an implementation detail, which is why the predicate is implemented as it is.

Comment: I'm having a problem here.  I am passing 47 as an argument, but IsInt32 is returning false.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: @JessePepper IsUint32 also return false?

Comment: `if(!args[1]->IsInt32()) 
{ 
    cerr << "not int32";
}

auto keyId = args[1]->Int32Value(); 
`

keyId has a sensible value, like 47 even though the error "not int32" is printed out.

Comment: What value did you pass into the function. `foo(42)` ? or `foo("42")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line;

`bool isInt = ( num->NumberValue() ) % 1 == 0;`

[NumberValue](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L1460) returns a `double` with the number's value, and the `% 1 == 0` will return true if the value returned is evenly divisible by 1.